# How do you write about someone carrying someone who broke their leg?

Tags: creative-writing, creativity

I’m writing about a certain scene where they find that one of the side characters has been hurt by bullies. I’ve tried to see if carrying bridal style would help, it didn’t help visually. Any suggestions?

Comment: Bridal carry is extremely exhausting for the rescuer, messes up their balance, and if I'm not mistaken, it isn't a good position for the injured person either. I guess a single rescuer would be most likely to take their friend in fireman's carry, over the shoulders. (Two rescuers have wider options.) But I'm no expert, so do as the answer advises and research.

Comment: You can even try roleplaying it with a friend willing to assist (without actually breaking their leg, obviously) to get firsthand experience what it's like to carry a person in various types of carry and gauge if your protagonist could do it under the conditions of the scene.

Comment: Visit your local firefighter or EMT station (preferably at a moment they aren't attending an emergency), and ask them for help. Most of the time, they will be happy to help with some pointers.

Comment: Carrying the injured person seems quite unrealistic to me.  When I've been in this situation, I've either hopped with support on the injured side and my own hand on the landscape for the other side, or shuffled backwards on my arse using my good leg, with the injured one supported by the rescuer.  Running around with a casualty in your arms is strictly for the movies!

Answer (score 6):

You don't need writing advice, you need to do research. How are people carried, when they have broken a leg? I'm sure with all the wars going on in the world you will find plenty of images, videos, or instructions for how to get your wounded mates out of the battlefield.

Comment: First aid would probably help though it would start with "don't do it!"

Answer (score 1):

As someone who had first aid training, do not move the guy unless his safety is in imminent risk. You want to have the broken limb move as little as possible.  In your scenario. you're supporting a bulk of the vic's weight with his knees, which would hurt if his leg was broken.   You should first find something like a brace or splint to tie his leg two. (A stick or board that can run the length of the leg).  Finding the rope or other item to tie is more important with a broken leg, because, if all else fails, you can tie his busted leg to his good leg.).

If you don't need to move him, then do not.  Activate EMS (in U.S./Canada/Mexico, this is 911.  Use your jurisdiction's equivalent) and try to keep the vic from moving while you wait.  Keep him talking and distracted from the current situation (typically dwelling on injuries will lead to shock, which isn't fatal... but doesn't help matters any).

But even after doing this, bridal carry is not the best option in this scenario.   Or any first aid scenario.  Ever.